# Ler dados de entrada até EOF no URI Online Judge

Tags: java

Olá, estou tentando resolver o seguinte problema abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, estou tendo problemas em colocar essa condição do EOF em java. Aqui no stack encontrei tentativas de soluções, porém elas são relacionadas ao uso de arquivos, e pro meu problema ai não se utiliza arquivo.

Por exemplo:

```
while (fileReader.nextLine() != null) {
    String line = fileReader.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Mas isso é com o uso de arquivo, que não é o meu caso.

Meu problema é representar esse EOF em java. Segue a parte do meu código que estou com problema:

```
public class Main {      
public static void main(String[] args) {        

    while(?){   //Condição de parada EOF
      ... código ...
    }
```

Se me recordo bem, em C eu poderia fazer algo como...

```
while (number != EOF);
```

Mas como eu posso fazer isso em java?

---

Resolvi o problema em C, fica assim:

```
int main(){
int N = 0;
while(scanf("%d",&N) != EOF){
... código ...
}
```

Mas gostaria de resolver em java, até o momento estou sem solução, alguma dica?

Comment: a condição de parada não seria o número de entrada que você indicou? 4 ou 7 por exemplo? nesse caso poderia colocar um contador dentro do while que vá incrementando até chegar no número, e quando o número for maior ou igual a condição de parada, ele para o while. int contador = 0; while(numeroEntrada > contador){ contador ++; }

Comment: @Geferson, não, 4 e 7 representa a dimensão da matriz. Pelo que entendi do problema meu programa deve receber várias entradas, tipo:
4
7
8
10
50
...
E o critério de parada é o EOF. Então depois de passarem todas as entradas, devo imprimir todas as respectivas matrizes. Porém não entendi como devo fazer esse critério de parada, ou seja, como representar esse EOF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simples, utilize um objeto [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) e chame o método [readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) até que ele retorne `null`. Lembrando que o método `readLine()` da classe `BufferedReader()` retorna uma `String`. E como no seu exercício você está lidando com um número, basta converter a `String` para `int`. Exemplo:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String linha;

        while ((linha = br.readLine()) != null) {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(linha);
            // TODO: lógica
        }
    }

}
```

Funcionando com alguns valores de exemplo no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/bh1OnS).

[Eu já tinha resolvido esse exercício no URI há alguns anos](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/ranks/problem/1534/java) (sou o 7º colocado ali), e fiz isso utilizando exatamente o mesmo código de leitura que postei acima (exceto a lógica do problema em si, obviamente).

Comment: Não deu certo. Eu informo uma linha com entradas: 10 5 9 8 25, dou enter e ele não faz nada. Se em seguida eu informo mais uma entrada (após o enter) ele imprime o resultado. Estou um pouco confuso quanto a condição de entrada do problema, não sei se devo representar o EOF como -1 ou outra coisa. Meu palpite é de que devo fornecer uma linha com várias entradas, ou seja, 10 20 30 5 9 45 7... e em seguida imprimir as respectivas matrizes.

Comment: @FilipiMaciel vi que você atualizou sua pergunta **após** eu ter dado um exemplo concreto aqui, então pelo jeito não tinha contribuído. Ajustei um pouco mais minha resposta. Espero que dessa vez sim dê certo :).

Comment: Devo ter me esquecido de voltar aqui ontem por estar envolvido com o problema. Caraca Tayllan, que bacana! sua solução deve ter uma lógica muito boa. Eu resolvi o problema com base na sua resposta ai, ficou um pouco diferente, mas basicamente é a mesma coisa. A parte do EOF ta resolvido, agora é o run time hehe mas isso eu resolvo la no URI, muito obrigado!

Comment: Como poderia ser solucionada em Python? Não consigo encontrar em lugar nenhum algo a respeito, e por conhecidencia, é uma questão do URI também: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1215

Answer (score 2):

Também da para fazer da seguinte maneira

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 while(br.ready()){...
```

assim quando acabar o arquivo sairá no laço while